# How to set the transition out duration in unity ui builder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

When i hover over the button it changes the color expectedly but when i hover off it it roughly about 3 seconds to change back to normal. Here is an image ->[Picture of UI Builder Pseudo Class hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhh3y.png)

I tried setting the transition duration and delay to 0 so that the the transition back should be instant.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you share at least a snippet of your code where this logic takes place please